# While loop Segmentation fault

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that reads from a file directed to stdin and then finds the two most used words in the file. I had almost everything working correctly but now am having odd segmentation errors with my while loop

```
char *word=readWord();
int end=0;
while(end==0&&word!=NULL){
    printf("word readn %s\n",word);
    list=addToList(list,word);
    printf("added to list\n");
    word=readWord();
    if(word==NULL){
        end=1;
        printf("word is null\n");
    }
}
printf("done while loop");
```

The output from this is as follows when run using a file that has the words one two three four.

```
word readn one
added to list
word readn two
added to list
word readn three
added to list
word readn four>
added to list
word is null
Segmentation fault
```

`readWord` function works fine in other files;

```
char * readWord(){

    //temporary char array to read string
    char c,word[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if(scanf("%c",&c)==EOF){
        return NULL;
    }
    while(!((c>='a'&&c<='z')||(c>='A'&&c<='Z'))){
        if(scanf("%c",&c)==EOF)
            return NULL;
    }
    int i;
    for( i=0;(c>='a'&&c<='z')||(c>='A'&&c<='Z');i++){
        word[i]=c;
        scanf("%c",&c);
    }
    word[i+1]='\0';

    //dynamic allocation of just enough memory to store the word
    char * str= malloc(strlen(word) +1);
    strcpy(str,word);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: might need ``addtoList`` and your sample file. 'Cause ``word readn four>`` this line, if not a typo, seems different from others.

Comment: `scanf(3)` returns the number of items matched, comparing to `EOF` makes little sense. Presumably you want to read single characters with `c = getchar()` instead.

Comment: @vonbrand It makes sense. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ says *If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.*

Comment: Gonna need `addToList` at least, ideally also BUFFER_SIZE and the structure definition of your list construct. Your while loop could become quite-trivial if you dropped a well-placed `break` in there. Also, `fgetc()` may well be considerably simpler to use rather than polluting your code with all those `scanf()` calls. Your processing chars, it doesn't get much more basic that that, so keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that the value of i at the end of your for loop is one more than the length of the word so this is incorrect:

```
word[i+1]='\0'
```

It should be:

```
word[i]='\0'
```

Couple of other comments:

- use isalpha(c)
- collapse malloc/strcpy into strdup
- write end==0&&word!=NULL as (end == 0) && (word != NULL)

Comment: didnt fix the problem i was having but did fix a few others

Comment: I hope you were able to fix your original problem.